# Wacom Tablet ShortCuts Key - Create Keystroke similar to Wacom's Tablet->Erase shortcut

Tags: shortcut, onenote, keystroke, wacom, eraser

In particular, I'm interested to make a Keystroke shortcut such that is works similarly as the pen's Tablet -> Eraser shortcut key, except for OneNote's Panning Hand.

That is to say, the Panning Hand will only be activated as long as the pen button is held, and then I will have the same OneNote Drawing/Writting properties as soon as I let go of the button.

As of now, I have created the Keystroke Alt-H to access the Panning Hand, which is suboptimal because I have to manually return to my drawing settings every time I have used the keystroke and want to return to my writing.

One idea that I have is looking up how Wacom Tablet's shorcuts are defined, and hope that I can replicate the idea to a new Keystroke command, which instead of accesing OneNotes' eraser, it activates the panning hand. However, I think this would warrant another post for the question.

I would apreciate your help greatly, as this is the only thing that keeps me from using OneNote.

Good day,

[image: Wacom Tablet Properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest answer to what you have described is to use the `Pan/Scroll...` option in the `Navigation` menu. While holding down the pen button you are able to scroll and when you release the button you can draw again.

You can view the setting I am reffering to by clicking [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuxA1.png).

Comment: This does the desired work. Thank you sav for your contribution.